# Free DBMS with encryption support and without size limitations

Tags: sql-server, encryption, database

I really need a free database which supports encryption, but doesn't have size limitations like 4 GB in SQL Server Express.
Suggestions welcome!

Comment: The size limit of SQL Express is now 10GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL sounds like a fit here...